# Select deeply nested element

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I'm reading Scrapy/XPath tutorials but this does not seem trivial and I can't find an example that would explain it.

Given a markup like this how would you select the `<span>` element?

```html
<div id=”...”>
 <div>
 <div>
 <div>
  <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <span>
```

If we generalize the problem it would be:

- skip n divs in the div with id="..."
- skip m divs in the div
- ...
- select the span element in the div

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming indentation denotes containment in your example, the following XPath will select the `span` element for you:

```
//div[@id='...']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/span
```

Of course, if there are no other `span` elements beneath the id'ed `div`, you could jump right to it:

```
//div[@id='...']//span
```

Or if there are no other `span` elements in the entire document:

```
//span
```

Comment: Very definitive answer. Thanks!

Comment: It helped but for some reason I can't extract the selector. If I log the content it prints a "square" symbol.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing a complete example, but perhaps it's not showing the string value of the selected element as you're expecting.  Does it help to explicitly select the text nodes of the span (by appending `/text()` to your XPath?

Comment: No. It returns an empty list. It returns a non-empty value only for //div[@id='...'], for all other nodes under it the selector returns an empty list.

Comment: If you provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem, it should be easy to see what's going on and help.  Thanks.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the referenced page does not have *any* children under `<div id="developer_blog_index" data-referrer="developer_blog_index"></div>`,  so of course you won't be able to select anything beneath there.

Comment: Strange, I can see the children (actually the whole content) under the div in the Chrome's element inspector. Maybe it loads it dynamically...